# shell scripting : I have a main directory which contain few other directories and I want to print all files inside those directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

This script only print files from main directory but doesn't print files of an sub directory that is present in main directory.

If not clear what I mean is if I have a main directory and that main directory has 5 sub directories and all of them contains file. I just want to print all of those files.

```
read filename
for entry in "$filename"/*
do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

Comment: `for entry in "$filename"/*/*`

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to print all of those files.

Then use `find`.

```
find "$filename" -type f
```

will print all filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask: which shell ? a Linux shell ? Powershell ?

If Powershell:

```
    $files = Get-Childitem -Recurse
```

Just don't use this starting at just the `C:\`.

But with your `read` and `echo`, it looks like Linux. have you tried the `tree` command?